# Eclipse debugging in ROS

Tags: eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

Being from a Windows background, I've found debugging on ROS (Ubuntu 10.10) fairly difficult and not very efficient. I had hoped that Eclipse would allow debugging of nodes launched using ROSLAUNCH, but so far, I have not been successful.

So, my questions:

1. Has anyone succeeded in debugging a ROS node launched by ROSLAUNCH in Eclipse?
2. If not using Eclipse or an equivalent IDE, do most of the members of the ROS community depend on the likes of gdb to perform debugging?

Regards, Billy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10091/eclipse-debugging-in-ros/) by [BillyG](https://answers.ros.org/users/611/billyg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've regularly debugged nodes inside of Eclipse. Is there a particular reason you need to launch your node with roslaunch? If you can launch it separately you should be able to create the eclipse project around your package with make eclipse-project, add it, compile it, and then run it in debug mode.

---

Originally posted by [pbrook](https://answers.ros.org/users/226/pbrook/) with karma: 226 on 2011-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bart](https://answers.ros.org/users/286/bart/) on 2011-05-28**:
I have been using the same strategy as Augusto with no problems for both nodes and nodelets. There was a recent posting that presented a method to execute a launch file from Eclipse, but I haven't tested it. Tags roslaunch and Eclipse.

**Comment by [Augusto Luis Ballardini](https://answers.ros.org/users/234/augusto-luis-ballardini/) on 2011-05-27**:
Same here: to debug a node I removed it from the launch file, run the launch-file in a separate terminal and then debug my code on eclipse. I agree with you, GDB is certainly not user friendly

**Comment by [Usman](https://answers.ros.org/users/25231/usman/) on 2016-09-20**:
In debug mode how can i put breakpoint which make compiler stop in each spin of ros or iteration?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's some information how to debug nodes inside Eclipse on [the IDEs page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs). It describes in some detail how to launch a single node in debug mode, while the rest are launched by a separate launch file.

Bonus tip: Eclipse also uses GDB internally, it just wraps it into a nice user-friendly interface. That means you can also use the [GDB pretty-printers](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport), which makes it possible to inspect vectors etc. directly via the Eclipse interface.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-05-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on 2012-10-26**:
Already, I have many built packages (without eclipse). If I need to use eclipse for debugging nodes in those built packges, Should I rebuilt those projects with eclispe or to make seperate copy and rebuilt it with eclipse? Which is possible and better one?

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-10-26**:
Don't make a separate copy, just create the eclipse project files (as explained on the IDEs page), import into eclipse (again, don't check "copy into workspace") and debug them. If the package is already built, you don't need to rebuild it from eclipse (but it doesn't hurt either).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I succeeded to debug a ROS node  launched by ROSLAUNCH in Eclipse.
I created the Eclipse project as described on [the IDEs page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs). I then created a "Debug configurations" with the type of "С/С++ Attach To Application".
After starting the ROSLAUNCH I click "Debug" in Eclipse and attach to the desired process.

---

Originally posted by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) with karma: 641 on 2011-06-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mercy](https://answers.ros.org/users/8381/mercy/) on 2015-01-30**:
Can I debug a particular package instead of the whole node in Eclipse? Suppose, I want to debug **navfn,** instead of debugging a **move_base node**?